# retrieve particular column between different columns of sqlite databse in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the code, by this I can retrieve all the columns data from the database. But the problem is that now I want to retrieve only one column, that is my requirement.[link1st](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387455/android-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-specific-data-from-particular-column) [link 2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653502/android-sqlite-how-to-get-particular-columnrow-value) [link3rd](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653502/android-sqlite-how-to-get-particular-columnrow-value)

```java
word_list = new ArrayList<>();
     SQLiteDatabase sd = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sd.query("stickerstable",null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            word_list.add(new data_items(

                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STICKER_AUTHOR)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STICKER_NAME)
                     )));

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        sd.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rawQuery** instead of **query**

```
Cursor cursor = sd.rawQuery("SELECT YOUR_COLUMN FROM stickerstable",null);
```

replace **YOUR_COLUMN** with the name of column you want to retrieve you can even use your Constants like this

```
Cursor cursor = sd.rawQuery("SELECT " + ID + " FROM stickerstable",null);
```

or a better way to use String.format

```
Cursor cursor = sd.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT %s FROM stickerstable", ID),null);
```

**UPDATE**

you can use **query** and specify the column in the second argument

```
Cursor cursor = sd.query("stickerstable",new String[]{ID}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

when you pass null means get all columns

Comment: thanks for your response.  in main activity retrieve two columns, name sticker author and sticker name, working fine . but if in 2nd activity i insert image in the sqlite and that image also show in the mainActivity list . what can i do.

Comment: actually i retrieve only two columns from database, but if insert image in database in 2nd activity it also show in mainActivity list.

Comment: i tried your code it wokings for retrieve all  data and the image also.. but it cannot solve my problems

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you, Can you update your question with more details and post more code

Comment: your Code is good for understanding , that's why i upvote your answer.. thanks.